# error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' in Visual Studio on building project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i am running an example project in visual studio downloaded from net. When i open project in visual studion 2015 and build the solution i get below errors, i dont know what i am missing here as it is already sample done and uploaded in net

```
 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: QvEventLogConnectorElaborate, Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(15,10,15,11): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(15,26,15,31): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(15,79,15,79): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(16,10,16,10): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(17,11,17,13): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(17,24,17,34): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(17,45,17,46): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(17,46,17,46): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,11,18,13): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,76,18,84): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,104,18,131): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,139,18,150): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,164,18,168): error CS1002: ; expected
1>C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\Standalone.Designer.cs(18,207,18,219): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Code is

```
    namespace QvEventLogConnectorElaborate
{
    partial class Standalone
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {< DirectedGraph xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml" >
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="(@1 @2)" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Node Id="(@3 Namespace=QvEventLogConnectorElaborate Type=Standalone)" Category="CodeSchema_Class" CodeSchemaProperty_IsPublic="True" CommonLabel="Standalone" Icon="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Class.Public" IsDragSource="True" Label="Standalone" SourceLocation="(Assembly=file:///C:/Users/star/Downloads/QvxSDK_2.1_x64/Examples/EventLogElaborate/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate/Standalone.Designer.cs StartLineNumber=2 StartCharacterOffset=18 EndLineNumber=2 EndCharacterOffset=28)" />
  </Nodes>
  <Links>
    <Link Source="(@1 @2)" Target="(@3 Namespace=QvEventLogConnectorElaborate Type=Standalone)" Category="Contains" />
  </Links>
  <Categories>
    <Category Id="CodeSchema_Class" Label="Class" BasedOn="CodeSchema_Type" Icon="CodeSchema_Class" />
    <Category Id="CodeSchema_Type" Label="Type" Icon="CodeSchema_Class" />
    <Category Id="Contains" Label="Contains" Description="Whether the source of the link contains the target object" IsContainment="True" />
  </Categories>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id="CodeSchemaProperty_IsPublic" Label="Is Public" Description="Flag to indicate the scope is Public" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="CommonLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="Icon" Label="Icon" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="IsContainment" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="IsDragSource" Label="IsDragSource" Description="IsDragSource" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="Label" Label="Label" Description="Displayable label of an Annotatable object" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="SourceLocation" Label="Start Line Number" DataType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.CodeSchema.SourceLocation" />
    <Property Id="Visibility" Label="Visibility" Description="Defines whether a node in the graph is visible or not" DataType="System.Windows.Visibility" />
  </Properties>
  <QualifiedNames>
    <Name Id="Assembly" Label="Assembly" ValueType="Uri" />
    <Name Id="File" Label="File" ValueType="Uri" />
    <Name Id="Namespace" Label="Namespace" ValueType="System.String" />
    <Name Id="Type" Label="Type" ValueType="System.Object" />
  </QualifiedNames>
  <IdentifierAliases>
    <Alias n="1" Uri="Assembly=$(VsSolutionUri)/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate.csproj" />
    <Alias n="2" Uri="File=$(VsSolutionUri)/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate/Standalone.Designer.cs" />
    <Alias n="3" Uri="Assembly=$(b696d163-8da0-45ae-a3db-010975425ad0.OutputPathUri)" />
  </IdentifierAliases>
  <Paths>
    <Path Id="b696d163-8da0-45ae-a3db-010975425ad0.OutputPathUri" Value="file:///C:/Users/star/Downloads/QvxSDK_2.1_x64/Examples/EventLogElaborate/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate/bin/Release/QvEventLogConnectorElaborate.exe" />
    <Path Id="VsSolutionUri" Value="file:///C:/Users/star/Downloads/QvxSDK_2.1_x64/Examples/EventLogElaborate" />
  </Paths>
</DirectedGraph>
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

After removing xml code in .cs file and rebuilding it, i get below errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: QvEventLogConnectorElaborate, Configuration: Release x86 ------    
1>  QvEventLogConnectorElaborate -> C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\bin\Release\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate.exe 
1>  relstamp file=[C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\bin\Release\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate.exe] 
1>  Exception in ParseBinaryVersionResource 
1>  Error in ParseBinaryVersionResource 
1>  error parsing version info from the file    
1>  Some of actions failed, exiting 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4713,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\verpatch.exe" "C:\Users\star\Downloads\QvxSDK_2.1_x64\Examples\EventLogElaborate\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate\bin\Release\QvEventLogConnectorElaborate.exe" /s "QlikView Connector" "Qv Event Log Connector Elaborate"   
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4713,5): error MSB3073: " exited with code 1. 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there supposed to be XML in your C# code?  I've never seen that before.  What is that even meant to do?

Comment: That is not valid c#, there's XML inside it.

Comment: @Daisy Your edit rendered the question completely useless. I reverted the edit, because otherwise nobody will be able to understand your question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid c#, there's XML inside it. The compiler fails on the first `<` it encounters. Remove the entire XML piece:

```
namespace QvEventLogConnectorElaborate
{
    partial class Standalone
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks those errors are now not shown after removing xml code. But i find new errors as mentioned above.

Comment: That's a new question. Deal with one question at a time here on Stack Overflow, please don't make moving target questions.